# Как объединить первый и второй массив по электронному адресу чтоб получить третий?

Tags: php

Массив первый

```php
array(8) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["fullname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test1@test.ru"
}
```

Второй массив

```php
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17572)
    ["username"]=>
    string(13) ""
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["fullname"]=>
    string(49) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test1@test.ru"
}
```

Такой результат нужен

```php
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17573)
    ["username"]=>
    string(13) ""
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(18) ""
    ["fullname"]=>
    string(47) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test1@test.ru"
```

объединилось через array_merge - отдельное спасибо @ArchDemon

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: тут только минусы ставят? и не помогают? вопрос же звучит, объединить два массива по полю электронный адрес, неужели непонятно? я уже даже выложил конечный результат, что получить нужно. Да я не знаю как объединить, поэтому прошу помощи профессионалов php помочь

Comment: @vladimir у вас пример очень тяжело выглядит, мало кто захочет в это вникать, упростите его до 1-2 элементов и тогда люди помогут
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Павел, спасибо, так нормально? или ещё меньше?

Comment: @vladimir гораздо лучше, но в идеале - сократить максимально, потому что без многих элементов проблема останется аналогичной, а визуальное восприятие возрастет

Comment: вам поможет `array_merge`

Comment: @ArchDemon в том то и проблема, что `array_merge`, добавит в конце дополнительные массив получается такое

```php
    array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int()
    ["username"]=>
    string(13) "test7@test.ru"
    }'''

а ниже добавляется такое
```php
    array(8) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["fullname"]=>
    string(28) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test1@test.ru"
    }```

`array_merge` - не подходит

Comment: @vladimir тут помогают разобраться с какой-то проблемой, а не решают задачи за вас. Для начала приведите код, который вы написали для того чтобы сделать то что вам нужно.

Comment: так вы объединяйте `$array1` и `$array2[0]` и складывайте опять в `$array2[0]`

Comment: @ArchDemon можно пример? кодом если не затруднит